# Disable the button when meet specific condition

Tags: java, android, view

I want to disable the button when the database title equals "Read".
my code is work but this scenario happens:

1. I entered the activity for the first time (the book unread yet).
2. I clicked the button --> it becomes disabled
3. I returned to the books list then entered rd the same book (the button enables now)
4. I went to the first homepage the repeat the scenario and in step 3 it becomes disabled

I need to make AlreadyRead button disabled, without having to go to the homepage, how?

My code:

```
public class BookData extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageView img;
    Button currently ,wantToRead, AlreadyRead, AddFavorites;
    TextView title,des;
    Book desierdBook;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_books);

        initViews();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        desierdBook =(Book) i.getSerializableExtra("obj");
        setData(desierdBook);
    }

    private void setData(Book book) {

        if(book.getState().equals("Read")){
            this.AlreadyRead.setEnabled(false);
        }

        title.setText(book.getTitle());
        des.setText(book.getDes());
        Picasso.get().load(book.getImg()).into(img);

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not "storing" the "read" state for that book in your database, but i can't be sure because I don't see in your code what happens when "AlreadyRead" is clicked.

When you serialize an object and deserialize it back it creates a new copy of the object so you cannot expect that your copy of Book will keep that state whatever it was sent to the activity through the Intent.

Make sure the state of "read" is saved into the database when clicking the button.

Comment: when I clicked the button my DB was update correctly

Comment: is there a way to send an object to another activity directly ? Without making a copy

Comment: how are you calling you BookData activity? what's the launchMode, it might be the intent holding on old data, and when returning you are receiving the new copy on onNewIntent.

Comment: Yup I think that happened because of the new copy of the object, but I don’t know how to resolve it

Comment: I called BookData activity when the user selects a book, and I send book's data on an intent

Comment: Ok, so you should pass the book id, and load from the database the book on BookData activity so you get data fresh from the database, so you just pass a string instead of a copy of the object